# Passing the onTouch() event to the underlying ViewGroup

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

If I have several ViewGroups overlap each other.  Is it possible to pass the onTouch() event of a ViewGroup to the underlying ViewGroup?

Each ViewGroup contains Views. But if a touch occurs in an area of a ViewGroup where no View that it contains occupies it, I would like to pass that onTouch() event to the next underlying ViewGroup which also contains Views.

Comment: "several ViewGroup overlap each other" Means?

Comment: Please let me know if I misunderstood your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I understand your question,

The `main ViewGroup` consume the `touch event` first, in that case,

Just **inflate your layout and make a View**..

then using that view define which view you have to use and `setOnTouch()`.. to that view..

For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xmllayout, null);
ImageView image_view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagView);

image_view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer in order to tell you whether you understand my question :)  I have added more details.. hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: Ok, for this as per my answer you have to just make a view using root view then by using it define underlying views and write onTouch for that views..

Comment: Basically, the answer was not to override the onTouch() method for the ViewGroup.